# C++17 fold syntax to test vector composition

Tags: c++, c++17, fold-expression

Standard C++17 implementation of vector `any`, `all`:

```
template<class C, class T>
bool contains(const C& c, const T& value) {
  return std::find(c.begin(), c.end(), value) != c.end();
}

template<class C, class... T>
bool any(const C& c, T&&... value) {
  return (... || contains(c, value));
}

template<class C, class... T>
bool all(const C& c, T&&... value) {
  return (... && contains(c, value));
}
```

for usage as in

```
std::array<int, 6> data0 = { 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14 };
assert( any(data0, 10, 55, 792));
assert( !any(data0, 11));

assert( all(data0, 6, 14, 8));
assert( !all(data0, 6, 7, 8));
```

Is there an analogous way to define `only`, which returns true if and only if the set of unique values of the vector matches the input values? So the following asserts would hold

```
std::array<int, 6> data1 = { 1, 1, 2, 1, 2 };
assert( only(data1, 1, 2));
assert( !only(data1, 1));
```

Comment: Are the values passed to `only` (the parameter pack) guaranteed to have unique values?

Comment: We can assume that yes.

Comment: While probably technically feasible, i don't think it makes sense to try and do it as a fold expression. In the std library functions you provided the list of values to check is expanded with the fold expression into individual values, but if your goal is to check for uniqueness, you need to know the full extent of the unique list, hence expanding the list would be counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<class C, class...Ts>
bool only( C const& c, Ts&&...ts ) {
  std::size_t count = (std::size_t(0) + ... + contains(c, ts));
  return count == c.size();
}
```

this counts how many of the list `ts...` are in `c`, and returns true if the number you found ear equal to the elements of `c`.  Now this assumes uniqueness of `c` and `ts`.

We just move the counting into `only` and test within the std algorithm:

```
template<class C, class...Ts>
bool only( C const& c, Ts&&...ts ) {
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  auto count = std::count_if( begin(c), end(c), [&](auto&& elem) {
    return ((elem == ts) || ...);
  } );
  return count == c.size();
}
```

and bob is your uncle.

We could also do a `notcontains` based `only` algorithm, but I think that is more complex.

Answer (score 3):

You can provide a `count` function:

```
template<class C, class T>
auto count(const C& c, const T& value) {
  return std::count(c.begin(), c.end(), value);
}
```

and write `only` like this:

```
template<class C, class... T>
bool only(const C& c, T&&... value) {
  return (count(c, value) + ...) == c.size();
}
```

This takes care of duplicate elements in `c`, but requires the `value`s to be unique.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/pMWpAZ).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't use fold expressions but it should work

```
template<class C, class... T>
bool only(const C& c, T&& ...vals) {
    auto ilist = {vals...}; //create initializer_list

    for (auto el : c) {
        if (!contains(ilist, el)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Something that uses fold expressions and not `std::initializer_list`

```
template<class T, class... Ts>
bool is_one_of(const T& val, Ts&& ...vals)
{
    return ((val == vals) || ...);
}

template<class C, class... Ts>
bool only(const C& c, Ts&& ...vals)
{
    for (const auto& el : c) {
        if (!is_one_of(el, vals...)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

// or if you hate raw loops
template<class C, class... Ts>
bool only(const C& c, Ts&& ...vals)
{
    using std::beign; using std::end;
    auto it = std::find_if(begin(c), end(c), [&](const auto& el) {
        return !is_one_of(el, vals...);
    });
    return (it == end(c));
}
```